# Windows domain controller errors

Tags: windows, domain-controller

I got the following errors when enquiring  two domain controllers.

> Cannot open security log for DC DC2.org - The interface is unknown.

and

> OpenEventLog failed for DC DC2.org(10.126.2.6) - The interface is unknown.

Google it, searched Windows articles but could not find the answer.

Has anyone seen this errors in production or knows the reason of it?

Comment: Are you opening remotely or locally (on the DCs or from another server)?  Have you ever been able to open the event logs on those servers?  Can you tell us the specific (through any service packs applied) OS version for the DCs (and if querying remotely, the query machine?  The Google is pointing towards one of two options:  problem with startup of event log service, or missing registry key:  http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/192894-46-error-1717-interface-unknown.